# Electron steals focus to Windows 10 Touch Keyboard and makes it unusable

Tags: windows-store-apps, touch, windows-10, electron

I'm trying to run the attached project on Windows 10 Pro (latest version available without Windows Insider Program).

Basically it is a fullscreen browser window that navigate to http://www.google.com.
I configured Windows in Tablet mode, in order to let the touch keyboard popup whenever any text field in the page (in this case the query one) gets focused.
Then, I packaged the application with [electron-windows-store](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-store) in order to let electron work as Windows Store application.

When I start the application and Google home page is loaded I'm not able to use the touch keyboard, because it pops up but immediately disappears, like if electron tries to acquire again focus and causes touch keyboard disposal.

I tried also to disable fullscreen mode and setup frame coordinates in order to be as it was in fullscreen, but no success.

Any suggestion?

[TestApp.zip](https://github.com/electron/electron/files/604228/TestApp.zip)
[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/conteit/electron-touch-test-app.git)

Comment: You should upload your code to a plunkr or github instead of attaching it to your post, very few people will touch that .zip.

Comment: https://github.com/conteit/electron-touch-test-app.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed it. The issue was caused by an old dependency to electron. Once updated it to the latest version I know (1.4.7) it all started working.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to an [open issue on the Electron GitHub repository](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6430). You might have to wait for the Electron team to introduce this improvement.